# PHPUnit in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

PHPUnit in PhpStorm. Everything working great, but why do I have this error?

[image]

The `Framework` shown in red, and the IDE error says:

> Undefined namespace Framework.

How to get rid of it ?

Comment: Are you talking about `Framework`?

Comment: Yes, it is in red

Comment: Its not error. Are you getting any error in execution?

Comment: I got no execution errors, everything works... only the IDE is complaining

Comment: This seems Notepad++. Its red because it is not able to recognize the syntax thats it. So probably you can find some plugin which could understand such syntax of dependency injection.

Comment: This is PHPStorm... no new syntax here, works ok with other namespaces..

Comment: Oh yes, sorry you have already said that this is PhpStorm. its very nice and has too many features.

Comment: Do you have PHPUnit installed and does PhpStorm know about its location? (in include paths, in project)? Do you have PHPUnit 6.x installed? It's the first version with namespaces.

Comment: 1) Based on screenshot -- please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE; 2) Do you have actually a PHPUnit (source files) in your project? It has to be either PHAR or Composer-installed version. 3) Have a look at this tutorials in case if you have not seen them yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Testing+PHP+Applications

Answer (score 1):

Phpunit introduced the namespace `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` with Version 6, early 2017 (see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-6.0.0).

Check your PhpStorm settings, probably you configured a version prior to 6.0.0, so PhpStorm doesn't know that namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. using phpunit.phar file

I fixed adding the file as External library
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Eyj.jpg)

I have several versions of phar so I just selected "exclude phar from project" in the other files.